# how to select an item in multiple dictionaries, python

Tags: python

First I defined : u = [ ], then I have

```
 u = {'flavor': {'version': u'X', 'name': 'MacOS'}, 
      'dist': {'version': u'AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8C148', 'name': 'iPad'}}
```

How can I select the 'iPad' field in u and assign this value to a string variable *terminal*?

Comment: Are you asking how to access elements in a dict, like u['dist']['name']?

Comment: Please.  Find a tutorial that you like and do the entire thing.  `iPad` is a value, not a key.   It's not a "field", either.  Do you want the value associated with the key of `'name'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I don't know what u = [] is meant to do.  It's not needed.)

Assuming I know what you mean by "the 'iPad' field":

```
>>> u = {'flavor': {'version': u'X', 'name': 'MacOS'}, 'dist': {'version': u'AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.8C148', 'name': 'iPad'}}
>>> terminal = u['dist']['name']
>>> terminal
'iPad'
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
terminal = u['dist']['name']
```